# Persits ASPPDF ImportFromUrl ServerXMLHTTP Error: The request has timed out

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, pdf-generation, serverxmlhttp

We have a test website that uses Persits ASPPDF to build a PDF using the ImportFromUrl method.  It works fine on our test domain, but when I use the same code on another domain (and crucially perhaps, a sub-domain) I get the "MSXML2::ServerXMLHTTP Error: The request has timed out." error.

This leads me to think its related to the problem outlined in

https://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS080709171

"the calling Active Server Page (ASP) should not send requests to an ASP in the same virtual directory or to another virtual directory in the same pool or process. This can result in poor performance due to thread starvation."

So perhaps the config of the two servers hosting the two sites (test and live) are different - and if so what would that be? - Or you can't run this method on a sub-domain?  Any guidance out there please?

Comment: I think that link is your answer, not sure what more you expect from us?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if the test domain and the sub domain ARE actually on the same server or not? If they are you probably already have your answer. If they're not then check the TLS versions in use and accepted on the website/server that hosts the code and makes the call, and the TLS versions accepted on the destination URL, and that they match up? Often ServerXMLHTTP timeouts or connection refusals are about this these days.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue for weeks and finally found out what the problem was. In my case, it was because I had set to `True` the options that allow the debug of classic ASP code, without which I could not debug using visual studio. Setting those options back to `False` fixed the issue.

[image]